# Как сделать платный доступ к разделам сайта?

Tags: php, sql

На сайте есть разделы которые должны быть доступны только после оплаты пользователем доступа к ним. В качестве платёжной системы использую Яндекс.Деньги. Так же хочу отметить что У каждого пользователя есть свой id. Суть проблемы: как мне в базе данных записать факт того что например пользователь с id оплатил услугу "стандарт"? Ранее пробовал в поле label формы оплаты передавать в виде строки через запятую нужные мне параметры (id пользователя, id оплачиваемой услуги и.т.д), но у этой строки есть ограничение длины в 64 символа да и сам метод костыльный. Есть ли какие-то более рациональные способы сделать вышеописанное?

Comment: Сделайте таблицу услуг с ценами. Сделайте связь услуга-пользователь, если пользователь оплатил услугу- добавляем запись в эту таблицу.
Далее, если пользователь заходит на закрытую страницу проверяем- есть ли запись в таблице услуг для этого пользователя: есть- пускаем на страницу, нет- редиректим на ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Сделать внутренний баланс пользователя, который пользователь может пополнить (в т.ч. через ЯД), а уже расчет за доступ брать с внутреннего баланса. Таким образом не будет проблем запомнить за что конкретно заплатил пользователь.

Comment: Идея хорошая, но в моём случаи это не совсем удобно, есть ли способ сделать так что бы пользователь оплачивал услуги и доступ  после этого открывался? Просто то что вы описали, создаёт лишний шаг при оплате. А этого допускать я крайне не хочу,  я хочу сделать так, что бы оплата была максимально простой для пользователя.